# Is there a way to create test summary from the existing test suites - in Microsoft TFS?

Tags: testing, tfs

I am struggling to find an efficient way to:
create TEST SUMMARY from the existing test suites, that can be put under task in TFS.

Currently, we export that somehow into Excel.

Looking for a way to create a TEST SUMMARY from the existing test suites, so that it can be stored in TFS.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? What's information do you want to get in TEST SUMMARY? How did you export to Excel? Did you try to add the Excel as attachment in the task work item?

Comment: Cece - 
a) We are currently using tfs version Version 16.131.28601.4
b) We need basic test summary information like - requirement id, bug id and the associated test cases id, title, configuration, testers, results.
c) We can copy all test cases in suite and paste in excel.
d) Looking for faster more robust way to get test summary in tfs.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Does the extension or API help you?

Comment: I tried extension - it is better than manual but not exactly what I am looking for.
Regarding API - i am trying to understand how to do that (to be honest).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check `Offline Test Execution` extension. With this extension, you can export the entire test plan, or a filtered selection, to an Excel file:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.OfflineTestExecution

Or you can use `Test Suites - Get Test Cases` REST API to get all test cases in a suite:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test%20%20suites/get%20test%20cases?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0

Comment: Thank you. How do i use the Rest API?
I am a beginner.

Comment: You could start REST API from the following links: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/rest/samples?view=azure-devops